# A horror movie about a group of young people in a haunted mansion

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm trying to locate a mockumentary horror movie.

I remember there were 4-6 friends, who came to a haunted mansion – to film paranormal activity. Right before some of the friends started to sneak into a private territory, they were stopped and warned by police to stop doing what they were doing. After pretending that they left, guys came back, also one of the guys tripped over something like a rope or idk, but it was sort of like a rope, and then came into the mansion. After they started looking for paranormal things, a ghost showed up. All of them tried to escape but all doors and windows were locked already. An operator (His name was Nick I guess) had been acting a bit weird, going crazy since the moment they sneak into the mansion. In the middle of the movie he made out with the ghost in the bathroom on the second floor. Then they started running, trying to get out, but in vain.

At the end of the film, one guy almost got out, but a huge number of ghosts appeared out of nowhere and, in an attempt to find a way out, he run into Nick, wanted to take him out with him, but he was possessed already and Nick killed him by driving him into a stake.

At the very end, all the characters were in a photo on one of the walls where was: either a camp / orphanage, or a family in front of this mansion.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8577370/?

Comment: By mockumentary, do you mean "[found footage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Found_footage_(film_technique))" or ["fake documentary"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockumentary)?

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this movie, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Or do you mean a mockbuster?

Comment: Yes, fake documentary. We watched it in either 2017 or 2018 and I believe it might’ve been made in 2013-2017, I also remember that it could be a 2016 movie but I’m not sure about it